# How to make Polygon shape work in Firefox?

Tags: css

I used the `shape-outside: polygon` to make the text aligned "diagonally". But, it doesn't work on firefox. Is there a way to make this work in firefox too with `clip path` or any other method?.

Here is the code I used:

```
-webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 71% 100%, 0 100%);
-moz-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 71% 100%, 0 100%);
shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 71% 100%, 0 100%);
```

Here if the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k57eLrgh/2/) to try this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check browser compatibility:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes
And may be this workaround will help: [CSS Shape Outside - Firefox Browser Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706119/css-shape-outside-firefox-browser-support)

Answer (score 0):

CSS shapes are not supported by Firefox.

http://caniuse.com/#search=shape

Comment: Connexo, Is there any other way to get what I need ?

Comment: You can go with SVG clippaths.

Comment: Could you please do the change in the fiddle and give me?? All I want is, "The text to be aligned diagonally on the left side".